# Is it possible to skip a package weak dependencies during a kickstart installation of Fedora?

Tags: fedora, dependencies, kickstart

I know how to skip the installation of weak dependencies with dnf when installing a package (either by modifying dnf.conf or directly in the command line). I was wondering: is it possible to skip a package weak dependencies during a kickstart installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just notice this question has not a definitive answer; I'll provide myself one after a bunch of years. To skip the installation of weak dependencies for packages included in the `%packages` section of a kickstart file, it's enough to use the `--excludeWeakdeps` option:

```
%packages --excludeWeakdeps
# your packages
%end
```

Answer (score 4):

**1. Command line parameter**

```
dnf --setopt=install_weak_deps=False newPackageName
```

**2. Permanent setting in the dnf config file**

```
sudo vi /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
```

add a line

```
install_weak_deps=False
```

Comment: The solution you provided is what is used to skip the installation of weak dependencies on a running system. On the question I specifically asked if there is a "documented" way to do that during a kickstart installation. @Salil